# How to prepend batch variable to filename on set of other variable?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

Code first:

```
ECHO off
SET home       = c:\Cygwin\home\ian
SET update_log = %home%\update.txt
                 ^^^^^^
```

Is there a way to prepend the `%home%` variable in the initialization of `update_log` variable as in the example shown above?

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Spaces on the left side of the equal sign are included in the variable name.
- Spaces on the right side of the equal sign are included in the variable value.

If the spaces in these places are not a requirement, don't use them

```
SET "home=c:\Cygwin\home\ian"
SET "update_log=%home%\update.txt"
```

Also, it is recomended to quote the assignments to prevent problems with special characters and to avoid the inclusion of spaces at the end of the value.

Answer (score 4):

Exactly as you have it, except batch is sensitive to spaces in a `SET` statement. `SET FLAG = N` sets a variable named "FLAG<kbd>Space</kbd>" to a value of "<kbd>Space</kbd>N"

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned. `set /a` can safely be used "quoteless".

So - remove the spaces

Comment: set /a can safely be used "quoteless" - as long no: logical shift, bitwise and, bitwise or, assignments with the previous operators are involved.